# after successfully register, i'm not able to login in express

Tags: express, authentication, passport.js

after successful register with passport in express, when i try to login. it failed and i don't know which code is causing error. please help.
here is my code.

```
router.post('/register',function(req,res){
//fetch user info
var firstName=req.body.firstName,
    lastName = req.body.lastName,
    mobile= req.body.mobile,
    email = req.body.email,
    password = req.body.password,
    newsConsent = req.body.newsConsent;

var userInfo = {firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, mobile: mobile, email:email, newsConsent: newsConsent };

//register and create user
User.register(new User(userInfo), password, function(error, userCreated)
 {
     if (error)
     {
        console.log(error);    
        //  req.flash("error", error.message);
         return res.render("auth/register");
     }
     else
     {
         req.login(userCreated, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
          }
          console.log(userCreated);
          return res.redirect('/');
        });
     }
 });
```

});

//login route

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", 
{
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/register"
}), function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
```

});

also please tell me how to know about the error in passport

Answer (score 0):

You need declare your strategy, serialize and deserialize. Here's my code. You can edit it as you need. FYI, I was using 'nip_nim' instead of 'username', so I set "usernameField" as nip_nim. Here I also use 'flash' package to save my notification data.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'nip_nim',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function (req, nip_nim, password, done) {
    var params = {
        nip_nim: nip_nim
    }
    var user = new User_Model(params);
    user.getDataUserByNIPorNIM()
        .then(function (result) {
            if (!helper.isExist(nip_nim) || !helper.isExist(password)) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('message_err', 'NIM/NIM dan password tidak boleh kosong.'));
            }
            if (!result) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('message_err', 'NIP/NIM yang anda masukkan salah.'));
            }
            if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, result.password)) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('message_err', 'Password yang anda masukkan salah.'));
            }
            return done(null, result);
        })
}));

//serialize and deserialize passport
passport.deserializeUser(function (nip_nim, done) {
    var params = {
        nip_nim: nip_nim
    }
    var user = new User_Model(params);
    user.getDataUserByNIPorNIM()
        .then(function (result) {
            done(null, result);
        })
});

passport.serializeUser(function (req, user, done) {
    done(null, user.nip_nim, req.flash('message_success', 'Welcome, ' + user.nama_unit_org + "."));
});
```

Comment: thanks @Hendro Febrian for quick help. if i can use 'email' instead of 'nip_nim'.

Answer (score 0):

ok. i found the culprit. it's not passport, it's mongoose schema. 
i have to add {index : true} in username.

```
`username    : {type:String, unique: true, index: true},`.
```

after that everything works fine.